# Why does my nested SQL SELECT returns either null or 'more than one row'?

Tags: mysql, sql

I went through similar questions here, but no solution given there works for me.

The idea is that I need to move data from old_database's OldDoc to new_database's NewDoc. The majority of the columns match, but there are two exceptions.

Namely, USER_ID column needs to be filled with an ID extracted from new_database's User table. What ID should be given to a record is decided by comparing old_database's OldDoc's operator column (it contains just the name of the user) to a name within new_database's User table which contains names and IDs.

So if old_database's OldDoc's operator column contains a row 'Nezuko-chan' and new_database's User table has Name column saying 'Nezuko-chan' and ID column saying '666', then new_database's NewDoc's USER_ID column should be given '666' here.

Basically the same logic applies to LOCATION_ID -> there's a Location table in new_database with Name and ID and, by comparing old_database's OldDoc's lokalizacja column (with just a name) to new_database's Location's Name column, I want to extract new_database' Location's ID for that name.

Below code...

```
INSERT INTO new_database.NewDoc (ID, NR_DOC, NR_HANDLE, DOC_DATE, PLANNING_RELEASE, QUANTITY, CASES, VOLUME, ZAPIS, USER_ID, LOCATION_ID, TYPE_ID)
SELECT 
    ol.id,
    ol.nrWZ,
    ol.nrHandle,
    ol.dataWZ,
    ol.planowaneWydanie,
    ol.qty,
    ol.cart,
    ol.volume,
    ol.Zapis,
    (SELECT u.ID FROM new_database.User u WHERE u.NAME = ol.operator),
    (SELECT loc.ID FROM new_database.Location loc WHERE loc.NAME = ol.lokalizacja),
    1
FROM  old_database.OldDoc ol
```

... results in this festival of errors:

```
Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null
Column 'LOCATION_ID' cannot be null
Subquery returns more than 1 row
Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null
Column 'LOCATION_ID' cannot be null
Subquery returns more than 1 row
Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null
Column 'LOCATION_ID' cannot be null
Subquery returns more than 1 row
Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null
Column 'LOCATION_ID' cannot be null
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.id,
    ol.nrWZ,
    ol.nrHandle,
    ol.dataWZ,
    ol.planowaneWydanie,
    ol.qty,
...' at line 3
```

I also tried replacing the syntax of my nested SELECTs with the below...

```
(SELECT u.ID FROM new_database.User u, old_database.OldDoc omg WHERE u.NAME = omg.operator),
(SELECT loc.ID FROM new_database.Location loc, old_database.OldDoc omg WHERE loc.NAME = omg.lokalizacja)
```

... which changes nothing.

This needs to be a mistake on my part as none of the columns I am trying to reach for is empty. Data is everywhere (checked by independent SELECTs).

I suppose the problem lies with my nested SELECTs which return "lists of results" instead of a single result for every row. Again, I checked similar questions before and can't find answers there so I must be making a very... individual kind of a mistake.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Kind Regards,
Bartek

Comment: You cannot use `old` alias for table name - it is reserved for referencing to old row values in a trigger.

Comment: My bad here, but I just used this alias here, it's a different one in the actual SQL. I will change it to avoid misleading people.

Comment: @Akina, is `old` really reserved? "_OLD; added in 8.0.14 (nonreserved)_" https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-D. Also `select 1 as old` works fine.

Comment: @jarlh This is legal as column alias rather than table alias. Of course it is possible that the parser will distinguish that this is not trigger-like reference but no guarantee, so it is safe not to use it as table alias.

Comment: @Akina, ANSI SQL and most dbms products have old as reserved. Reason enough to avoid it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT .. SELECT` with proper joining:

```sql
INSERT INTO new_database.NewDoc (
    ID, NR_DOC, NR_HANDLE, DOC_DATE, 
    PLANNING_RELEASE, QUANTITY, CASES, VOLUME, 
    ZAPIS, USER_ID, LOCATION_ID, TYPE_ID
)
SELECT ol.id, ol.nrWZ, ol.nrHandle, ol.dataWZ, 
       ol.planowaneWydanie, ol.qty, ol.cart, ol.volume, 
       ol.Zapis, u.ID, loc.ID, 1
FROM old_database.OldDoc ol
JOIN new_database.User u ON u.NAME = ol.operator
JOIN new_database.Location loc ON loc.NAME = ol.lokalizacja;
```

Maybe LEFT JOIN needed (if some row have no according value in `User` or `Location`).

Of course `NAME` in both ref. tables must be unique.

---

For "column .. cannot be NULL" - alter table definition and add correct DEFAULT value to each column mentioned in the errors list.

Comment: Thank you for the time to look into my issue and pointing out the proper way. The previous error is resolved and it seems it's about to work... It's just I still have a problem with one nrWZ being duplicated and am still looking for a way to circumvent the "SQL Error [1062] [23000]: Duplicate entry 'XXX for key 'NR_DOC_UNIQUE'", but you clearly put me on the right track here, so I am marking your input as the answer.

Comment: For the record... INSERT IGNORE INTO (...) and the issue is but a memory.